# Cannot analyse memory usage per object type in .Net Framework application dump

Tags: c#, .net, debugging, memory-leaks

I have a .Net 4.x application with a memory leak that consumes about 1GB per month which I would like to fix. Therefor I am looking for a way to figure out which object type is using the memory and/or is not garbage collected over time.

So far, I created a dump with

```
dotnet-dump collect -p 12345
```

and loaded it with

```
dotnet-dump.exe analyze mydump.dmp
```

Now if I try to analyze the heap using

```
dumpheap -stat
```

I get

```
Failed to load data access module, 0x80004002
Can not load or initialize mscordacwks.dll. The target runtime may not be initialized.
For more information see https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=2135652~
```

even if I set the path to "mscordacwks.dll" as suggested explicitly by

```
setclrpath "C:/Windows/Microsoft.NET/Framework64/v4.0.30319/"
```

Can someone please help me with the dotnet-dump tool OR provide another way to analyse the memory usage of the application (without running it in debug mode)?

Comment: `dotnet-dump` is for .NET Core, isn't it? If you're stuck with 4.X, why not use CLRProfiler?

Comment: thanks, I will take a look at CLRProfiler.  it seems to be out of action since about 10 years, so I would expect some other tool from MS which is not .NET Core specific. also, its reported to slow down the application quite a bit and cannot be used for production.

Comment: @Luaan thanks again for the tip, for my issue, it looks like MS has integrated this profiler into the VS Diagnostic Tools https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/profiling/memory-usage?view=vs-2022 . Here and there, I need a new run to analyze the heap, while running the tool at the same time. Now the goal would be to dump on production the heap and run the tool on it. theoretically I see no problem, but I still have not figured out how to do it

Comment: There's many ways to do the memory dump in production; the simplest is probably `procdump` from Sysinternals, which allows you to take full memory dumps, as well as configure things like "dump when committed memory exceeds 4 GiB". Then you can analyse the dump at your leisure and with a tool of your choice (WinDbg, CLRProfiler etc.).

Comment: thats exactly where I failed so far - matching a dump-method and a analysing tool which are convenient for .NET4.X. E.g. with CLRProfiler, I dont see an option to read a dump-file.
so you say, if I dump my .net4-app with procdump, I can open the file with WinDbg and get an analysis of the heap (count/sizes per object type)?

Comment: You need to do a full dump, then you can open it in WinDbg with the right SOS version setup. `!dumpheap` and `!GCRoot` are a good starting point. You can also use `!TraverseHeap` to export a log that can be imported into CLRProfiler (File->Open log file). WinDbg and SOS are very powerful tools, but it takes a while to learn to use them :)